# In my Tab Bar View, my TableView cannot load data when launched but data would then appear when I click away and click back

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to load a list of titles from reddit.com/.json, but my tableview under a UIViewController would not load data whenever I launch it, the screen would be blank like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjXSg.jpg

I have to click the Downloads Tab and then click back to the Current Sub tab in order for my TableView to properly load data from the json file:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gRiW.jpg

I also attach my code of the ViewController for that tab in this question to see if anyone can spot where I have done wrong.

```
import UIKit

class CurrentSubViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,NSURLConnectionDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate {

    var manager:DataManager = DataManager()
    var localJson:JSON=JSON.nullJSON
    @IBOutlet var tableView : UITableView!
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager.startConnection()

        print("subredditview loaded")

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {

        return manager.json["data"]["children"].count
    }
    // Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
    // Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        let cell = self.tableView?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TitleCell",forIndexPath:indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        let row=indexPath.row
        print("got here /table view yeah")

        cell.textLabel?.text = manager.json["data"]["children"][row]["data"]["title"].stringValue
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = manager.json["data"]["children"][row]["data"]["author_name"].stringValue

        /**if !json["data"]["children"][row]["data"]["thumbnail"].stringValue.isEmpty
        {
            let thumbnailPath=json["data"]["children"][row]["data"]["thumbnail"].stringValue
            let thumbnailURL:NSURL=NSURL(string: thumbnailPath)!
            let thumbnailData=NSData(contentsOfURL:thumbnailURL)
            let thumbnail=UIImage(data:thumbnailData!)
            cell.imageView?.image=thumbnail
        }**/
        return cell
    }

     func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        manager.query="http://reddit.com/r/"+searchBar.text+"/.json"
        manager.data=NSMutableData()

        manager.startConnection()
        tableView?.reloadData()
    }

        /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way to solve this problem is start the networkActivityIndicator when data is receive from the server this way:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
```

after that when data is received you can set network activity to false and when the network activity is done you can reload your tableView this way:

```
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible == false{
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }
```

and your code will be something like this:

```
import UIKit

class CurrentSubViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,NSURLConnectionDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate {

var manager:DataManager = DataManager()
var localJson:JSON=JSON.nullJSON
@IBOutlet var tableView : UITableView!
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    manager.startConnection()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    print("subredditview loaded")

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{

    return manager.json["data"]["children"].count
}
// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell = self.tableView?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TitleCell",forIndexPath:indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let row=indexPath.row
    print("got here /table view yeah")

    cell.textLabel?.text = manager.json["data"]["children"][row]["data"]["title"].stringValue
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = manager.json["data"]["children"][row]["data"]["author_name"].stringValue

    /**if !json["data"]["children"][row]["data"]["thumbnail"].stringValue.isEmpty
    {
        let thumbnailPath=json["data"]["children"][row]["data"]["thumbnail"].stringValue
        let thumbnailURL:NSURL=NSURL(string: thumbnailPath)!
        let thumbnailData=NSData(contentsOfURL:thumbnailURL)
        let thumbnail=UIImage(data:thumbnailData!)
        cell.imageView?.image=thumbnail
    }**/
    return cell
}

 func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    manager.query="http://reddit.com/r/"+searchBar.text+"/.json"
    manager.data=NSMutableData()

    manager.startConnection()
    tableView?.reloadData()

   UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible == false
   if UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible == false{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
}

    /*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

I didn't test it but let me know if it works for you.
try this may be this will help you.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I now think the problem exist because my viewcontroller would load the table view only when the tab is touched. I wonder if there is a way to force the viewcontroller to reload tableview at any time?? Thanks in advance!